# Https (secure) lightbox login on a http page

Tags: http, https, security, pci-compliance

Is it possible, while being PCI compliant, to have a lightbox popup login that is secure (https) on a non-secure page (http)?  If so, would it show the proper security icons/locks on the page?

Answer (score 0):

This is vulnerable for multiple reasons.  An attacker can just use [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) to remove the https login and MITM the password.

Also why are you just using HTTPS for login?  It should be used for the entire life of the session or or its completely and totally useless.  You are violating OWASP A9 and this can be exploited with [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep).

Comment: "Completely and totally useless" is an overstatement. Directing a user to HTTPS for login prevents their login credentials from being hijacked, and given the rate of password re-use, this is a very useful thing. The user session can be hijacked, but not the user's other accounts. Also, if the appropriate measures are in place (e.g. requiring that the password be re-entered over HTTPS before certain actions), the session itself may be hijacked but the attacker is limited in the actions he or she can perform with it.

Comment: @Ben what if its an admin account?   I still stand by OWASP, HTTPS is all or nothing.

Comment: if it's an admin account then not using HTTPS is definitely a terrible idea. And I totally agree it's ideal to follow OWASP to the letter.  But in a hypothetical case where someone's unable to get budget resources to go all-HTTPS (say they're behind Akamai, which apparently can charge 2X or more for HTTPS traffic over HTTP), they'll be at least a little better off pointing login functionality to HTTPS, and also requiring password confirmation over HTTPS for any critical account change. It won't be the ideal implementation, but it won't be sending passwords in cleartext either.

Comment: @Ben Thats a rip off,  and it exposes your users to a attack.  Its nearly identical to forcing your application to have an XSS vulnerability,  any malicious person can just come along and snatch a session.   There can be a case where you juggle two session id's,  one has the "secure" flag set to always transmit over https and required for state changes.   But its a lot of complexity and I don't know of any applications that use this.

Comment: One example site with session in the clear: Stack Overflow. (I'm not sure what they do for admin interface, and if that's the same session cookie or a secure cookie)

Comment: Sorry @Rook, I see you're already aware of that from the relevant discussion on meta.so :)